# Как подключить Native Test Project к нативному С++ проекту?

Tags: юнит-тесты, visual-studio, c++

В туториале Microsoft написано что для того чтобы подключить Native Test Project к проекту на C++ (без clr-дополнений), нужно выполнить следующее:

1. Создать Native Test project.
2. В свойствах проекта, выбрать add references и добавить проект на C++.

Все, после этого я могу писать юнит-тесты для своего проекта. 
Проблема только в том что ни классов ни других элементов моего проекта в юнит-тест проекте не появляется (они не видны).
В чем может быть дело? 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ваши проекты нативные? Тогда скорее всего надо включить соответствующие header'ы.

Автоматическая видимость классов -- свойство .NET, в чистом С++ без header'ов не обойтись.

Comment: Не работает все равно. Не видит оно этих хедеров, даже после задания зависимостей.

Comment: @SoloMio: а вы в свойствах проекта include directories прописали? Без них, понятно, не увидит.